# Is there a term to describe phrases like "vulcan mind meld", "circle the wagons", "900 pound gorilla"?

Tags: expressions

My cube neighbor can't seem to say a sentence without using a phrase like I've included in the title.  Is there term that characterizes phrases like these?  More examples are "in the ballpark", "in my back pocket", "close to the vest"

Comment: In England, we might say "Bollocks", but I guess that's not helpful!

Comment: And tell your cubemate that it's "800 pound gorilla".

Answer (score 5):

Those are [*idioms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom).

> An **idiom** (Latin: *idioma*, "special property", f. Greek: *ἰδίωμα – idiōma*, "special feature, special phrasing, a peculiarity", f. Greek: *ἴδιος – idios*, "one’s own") is a phrase or fixed expression that has a figurative, or sometimes literal, meaning. An idiom's figurative meaning is separate from the literal meaning.

Overused idioms often become [clichés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clich%C3%A9), which might also be the word you're thinking of.

Comment: Thank you. I should have known that but couldn't think of the word.